# HTTP request and IP address

Tags: java, http, http-headers, netty

I have got the ip address from the HTTP request object using

request.getRmeoteAddr() => 127.0.0.0

However im using netty and when I use

```
SocketAddress socketAddress = channel.getRemoteAddress();
InetSocketAddress inetAddr = (InetSocketAddress)socketAddress;
ipAddress = inetAddr.getAddress().toString();

=> 0.0.0.0.0.1
```

This is causing me problems when trying to compare, i want them in the same fomrat...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use getHostAddress(); that should do it.

```
InetSocketAddress inetAddr = (InetSocketAddress)socketAddress;
String address = inetAddr.getAddress().getHostAddress();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress()

Comment: SocketAddress socketAddress = channel.getRemoteAddress();    
  String ipAddress = socketAddress.toString();
  LOGGER.info("ip address from socket: " + ipAddress);
  
  //if(socketAddress instanceof InetSocketAddress){   
   InetSocketAddress inetAddr = (InetSocketAddress)socketAddress;
   InetAddress inetAddress = inetAddr.getAddress();
   LOGGER.info(inetAddress.getHostAddress());

Answer (score 1):

When you've a class that represents something that can be represented as lots of different strings, then don't compare the strings; compare objects of that class.

Comment: but im storing the address. So needed to compare the address

Comment: So parse the address into an object of that type?